# Definition of likelihood function on Wikipedia

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

In [Likelihood function page of Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function), the definition of likelihood is written as below:

> Given a probability density or mass function
>
> $x \mapsto f(x\mid\theta),$ (1)
>
> where x is a realization of the random variable X, the likelihood function is
>
> $\theta \mapsto f(x\mid\theta),$ (2)
>
> often written
>
> $L(\theta\mid x).$ (3)
>
> In other words, when $f(x\mid \theta )$ is viewed as a function of x with $\theta$ fixed, it is a probability density function, and when viewed as a function of
> $\theta$ with x fixed, it is a likelihood function.

I interpret the formula (2) as the function f is a function of of x with $\theta$ fixed.
Then it seems to me that formula (2) and the sentence "when viewed as a function of
$\theta$ with x fixed, it is a likelihood function" contradicts.
Assuming that in this sentence "a fucntion" refers to L makes more sense.
But then my next question is how (2) can be written as (3) where two variables($\theta$, x) are exchanged?

Where am I misunderstanding of the fomulas?

Comment: It is clearly written that in the case of likelihood $\theta$ is the domain ($\theta$ maps to the  range of the function). Why do you interpret likelihood as a function of $x$?

Comment: @kludg Thanks for your reply. $\theta$ maps to the range of $f(x\mid\theta)$, but this function is still function of x with $\theta)$ fixed is what I thought. Is that incorrect?

Comment: sidenote: I was thinking $\theta$ fixed because I thought that the function is conditonal probability of x given $\theta$.